# importing data from log to sql table with delimter

Tags: datetime

have a sql table with the columns and want to import it into the sql table, at the same time remove the hypnens under the column and the last delimter. please help.

```
timestamp          |cp |type    |count      |fail_count |succ       |fail       |
-------------------|---|--------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
2014.12.15 00:00:00|  1|       5|          5|          0|        143|          0|
2014.12.15 01:00:00|  1|       5|         30|          0|        945|          0|
2014.12.15 02:00:00|  1|       5|         30|          0|       1055|          0|
2014.12.15 03:00:00|  1|       5|         24|          0|        816|          0|
2014.12.15 04:00:00|  1|       5|         28|          0|        882|          0|
2014.12.15 05:00:00|  1|       5|          6|          0|        155|          0|
2014.12.15 06:00:00|  1|       5|         12|          0|        236|          0|
```

Comment: Where is your source data and what is your destination? eg: .csv to mysql/sql server

Comment: .log file in C drive to sql table